# Window service need access to shared folder

Tags: service, window

I have a window service that needs to check file in a shared folder.  It looks like it cannot see the file.  The shared folder is on a window server 2008.  The window service is on my computer and configured as local system.  I have a console app that can see the shared folder without any problem. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The service needs to be configured to run under the credentials of a user with permissions to the shared folder. The LocalSystem account only has permissions to the local machine. When you run your console application, it is running under your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your credentials must be given to the service

First you have to give the IP of the server and their credentials then this will connect to the shared folder

directly this will be not possible

because service has no rights to access shared folder